# Camunda spring boot starter : create database in schema not working

Tags: business-process-management, camunda

I have used the camunda spring boot startup project (1.3.0) to spin up my camunda engine with the rest api.

In my application.yml I am trying to get camunda to create the database objects for me in a certain schema.

The settings below create the db objects...

```
camunda.bpm:
  database:
   schema-update: create-drop
   type: postgres  
   table-prefix: my_schema.
spring.datasource:
  url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"
  username: myuser
  password: myuser
  driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
```

The problem though is that the tables get created in the public schema. What I want to do is add a table-prefix equal to "my_schema."

Am I using this setting incorrectly or is there something I am missing?

thanks

Comment: In plain Camunda (w/o spring boot starter), the engine can only automatically create the tables correctly, if it uses the default schema. When using a custom schema and table prefix, the create scripts should be applied manually. I don't know if the Spring Boot starter offers anything on top, but I guess it does not.

Comment: Is there any argument against just creating the tables in the schema given by property "camunda.bpm.database.schema-name"? Why did the Camunda team decide against this approach, @thorben?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
camunda:
  bpm:
    admin-user:
      id: ${CM_ADMIN_USR:admin}
      password: ${CM_ADMIN_PWD:admin}
    database:
      schema-update: false
      schema-name: camunda
      table-prefix: camunda.
```

Refer :

https://github.com/camunda/camunda-docs-manual/blob/master/content/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/configuration.md

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thorben is right: currently, camunda spring boot uses the normal database setup. So if (I actually never checked this) table_prefix is not supported, you cannot use it with spring boot.

I created an issue for removal: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter/issues/177

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by providing schema name as a suffix with the datasource URL

like :

```
url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?currentSchema=my_schema"
```

Thus the tables should be created under the specified schema.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the following steps to create the Camunda tables, .. in the schema called `my_schema`.

1. Create a new schema in your PostgreSQL database using the `CREATE SCHEMA` command:

   ```
   CREATE SCHEMA my_schema;
   ```
2. Grant all permissions on the new schema to the `postgres` user using the `GRANT` command:

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA my_schema TO postgres;
   ```
3. Set the search path to the new schema using the `SET search_path` command:

   ```
   SET search_path = my_schema;
   ```

   So that you can later check whether the tables were created successfully in the
   correct schema using the `\dt` command.
4. Update your application.yml file to specify the new schema in the JDBC URL and in the Camunda BPM configuration:

```
spring.datasource:
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5001/my_database?autoReconnect=true&currentSchema=my_schema # <-
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

camunda.bpm:
  admin-user:
    id: demo
    password: demo
  database:

    type: postgres
    schema-name: my_schema # <-
    table-prefix: my_schema. # <-
```

**Just a reminder:**
In PostgreSQL, a schema is a named collection of database objects, including tables, indexes, views, and sequences. Schemas are useful for organizing objects into logical groups, providing better security and access control, and avoiding naming conflicts.

cheers